# Unable to run C executable with libraries on other computers

Tags: c, cmake, clion

If anyone can help me with this that would be awesome because I've spent the last hour trying to figure this out

So I built a game in C using CLion and the RayLib library

This is what my CMakeLists.txt file looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(orbital_motion_sim_c C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(orbital_motion_sim_c main.c orbitalMath.h orbitalMath.c mainfunctions.c mainfunctions.h main.h sim.c sim.h mainmenu.c mainmenu.h instructions.c instructions.h)

target_link_libraries(orbital_motion_sim_c libraylib.a)
```

Now, whenever I go to run the executable file orbital_motion_sim_c on another computer, it outputs the following:

```
Last login: Sun Jan 19 16:36:36 on ttys000
/Volumes/MYVOLUME/cmake-build-release/orbital_motion_sim_c ; exit;
macs-iMac:~ JakobKoblinsky$ /Volumes/MYVOLUME/cmake-build-release/orbital_motion_sim_c ; exit;
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/raylib/lib/libraylib.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Volumes/MYVOLUME/cmake-build-release/orbital_motion_sim_c
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

I thought that by doing `target_link_libraries(orbital_motion_sim_c libraylib.a)` It would be able to run on any computer?

Comment: Libraries typically come with dependencies that may be missing in the aforementioned other computer.

Comment: Description "it says library not loaded."  is quite vague for us for being able to help you. Please, provide **exact error message**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev My bad I just added what it outputs on my other computer

Comment: According to the error message, you actually link a **dynamic library** `libraylib.2.dylib`. Or `libraylib.a` is a actually a reference to the dynamic library. In any case, for being able to run your executable on "other computer", the dynamic library should exist there.

Comment: You can build an executable [and a shared/dynamic library] on one computer. To run it on another computer, that second computer must be [more or less] the same compiler, libc, OS, etc. Otherwise, you'll need to copy over the _sources_ and rebuild on the second computer (e.g. building on linux won't work too well when trying to run it under macOS). From your error message, as _Tsyvarev_ mentioned, on the second computer, it can't find the library. So, either you didn't copy over the library as well, or it's in the wrong place.

Comment: since you are on macos you can try to use `otool -L orbital_motion_sim_c` to see all dependencies your program depends on...